# How to find a youtube channel with a private video url only?

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to open a .rar file but it has password and it's in the description of a video on Youtube but when I checked the link again it was private and I don't remember the channel's name, so I just want to know if there's a way to find this channel because I just wanna ask to the user if I could have the password. This is the url if it helps, thanks.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6rTPvftDHtQ

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't a programming related problem

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to do that. One hope would be the waybackmachine, but that has no snapshot of this video page either. So unfortunately you won't be able to search him I guess.

Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I typed `"6rTPvftDHtQ"` on Google in order to have only webpages containing exactly `6rTPvftDHtQ`.

I let you find more details about the other interesting result except this StackOverflow post. The video gaming creator [Mataraxu](https://www.facebook.com/Mataraxu/) posted the URL of the video as a comment of a Facebook post and the post shares this YouTube channel URL https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1OnhcSrtZcaI4cgKAfsxsw. If he isn't the man you are looking for, I let you ask him more details.

[I WebArchived the webpage](https://web.archive.org/web/20220611114716/https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3AoC9bXhqbJzoJ%3Af.co) from the Google cache because his Facebook webpage doesn't seem to contain anymore this post (and comment), I let you delve this result.

By the way don't hesitate to check your web-browser history as you said that you already went to the video webpage. Maybe with luck you also went on the main webpage of the YouTube channel and then in the URL you would have its name or id.